# short description of how I approached my code

Tags: string

I wrote a code for a java problem and I want to write a short description of how I approached it but my english is not that good. How would I write something like that when I am not that good in words?

Comment: return String.format("%d\t%s", weight, query);         return weight + "\t" + query;        what do these mean ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use google translator. Or you can reach me and i can help with it!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).